# ReactiveBinding: Error when binding data using not (!) operator

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I'm trying to bind a field from a view model to a property of a control using **IReactiveBinding** from **ReactiveUI**, version **6.5.0.0**.

I would like to bind the negated value from the view model to the property of the control:

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => !vm.IsSmth, control => _checkBoxSmth.Enabled, _checkBoxSmth.Events().CheckStateChanged)
```

but I just get this error and can not find how to fix it.

*`System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression type: 'Not' caught here:`*

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of your problem is that `Bind` allows only properties in `vmProperty` and `viewProperty` arguments - you cannot alter them with function calls. If you don't want to alter your view model, you can use `Bind` overload which accepts [`IBindingTypeConverter`](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/3f725c808b1d4c8457f0d3204e0a071aa462cd75/ReactiveUI/RegisterableInterfaces.cs#L153) which will simply negate your boolean value. Here is an example of [`BooleanToVisibilityTypeConverter`](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/3f725c808b1d4c8457f0d3204e0a071aa462cd75/ReactiveUI/Xaml/BindingTypeConverters.cs) implementation.

Your code might look like this (note - I didn't test it):

```
public class NegatingTypeConverter : IBindingTypeConverter
{
    public int GetAffinityForObjects(Type fromType, Type toType)
    {
        if (fromType == typeof (bool) && toType == typeof (bool)) return 10;
        return 0;
    }

    public bool TryConvert(object from, Type toType, object conversionHint, out object result)
    {
        result = null;
        if (from is bool && toType == typeof (bool))
        {
            result = !(bool) from;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that if you use `OneWayBind`, you don't need to implement your own converter, there are overloads accepting fuction altering view model property (look for `selector` argument).

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. And just to have the entire answer for the question, the binding should be done then like this:
`this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.IsSmth, control => control._checkBoxSmth.Enabled, null, new NegatingTypeConverter(), new NegatingTypeConverter())`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you add a negative field and bind to that.
Here is a really simple concept example.

```
public class Model
{
    public bool IsSmth { get; set; }
    public bool IsNotSmth 
    { 
        get { return !IsSmth; }
        set { IsSmth = value; }
    }
}
```

And then bind like this.

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.IsNotSmth, control => _checkBoxSmth.Enabled, _checkBoxSmth.Events().CheckStateChanged)
```